# filter weekends from date histogram with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a specific use case that I'm struggling with. To give you more context, I have an index in Elasticsearch that has data related to working days only, so for a specific month I only have working days without weekends or holidays.

The problem for me is the data that I have is only produced in a specific day when there is activity, so if for example no activity has been done on monday 2018-12-09, I will not have this record.

I want to have a date histogram that ignores the weekends only, so I can have a final set of data including working days without activities, to be able to count them at the end.

So for example a query is like that for this month(December) :

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to have buckets, ignoring all the weekends.

If you guys have any ideas of how I should handle this issue, please give me your opinion.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell me if I got this right. You want to have one bucket per day, excluding weekends (Saturday, Sunday). Is that right? And even if for a given date there are no documents, return the bucket for that date with zero value. Right?

Comment: Yes correct that's what I want to do